# How many Microsoft JVMs still in the wild?

Tags: java, jvm, version

I know this question isn't exactly a programming question, but it will affect how we program one of our products, so i guess it might be close enough.

Do you guys still see the Microsoft JVM  (Java 1.1) on client computers anymore? I havent found much info on this particular JVM online...

Anyone know of a good resource to find this type of info? Sun's site is pretty much useless for this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I remember this being installed on work PCs around 2002. It is not supported by Microsoft any more. See- http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/java/default.mspx

I'd be surprised if you found many PCs that still had this on.

Comment: My instinct and experience tell me pretty much the same. The problem is that i need 'harder' data to convince management that we can stop worrying about such a relic...

Comment: If it's not a supported product, isn't that enough data? Why would you target any unsupported JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen it in this millennium I think.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind it would not be an unreasonable requirement to say Java 1.4 or later.

Your demographics may be different though, but I believe we talk about IE4 based systems which has been subsequenlty upgraded, and only those.

What is your product, and what does it need to do?

Answer (score 0):

One way to settle a question like this would be to get hold of your company's customer list, and them out a survey.  Or put a survey on your product website.

Or maybe you could buy one of those expensive "state of the industry reports" ... Gartner, etc.